# "Being open minded" vs. "the quality of being open minded"

Tags: word-choice, sentence

> - One of the most essential characteristics that all good leaders share is being open minded.
> - One of the most essential characteristics that all good leaders share is the quality of being open minded.

Both variations of this sentence sound awkward, I am not sure why. Can someone tell me if they are both awkward, pick which one is better or suggest an improvement?

Comment: It would not be easy to choose between your sentences.

Comment: I'd simplify it by rewording as follows: An essential characteristic of all good leaders is open-mindedness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a hint of pleonasm. I'd reduce it to:

One of the most necessary qualities of a good leader is having an open mind.